# Doctype validation W3C

Tags: laravel, doctype, w3c-validation

I built a simple website using laravel but i have problem with validation.I get a errors

"DOCTYPE" declaration not allowed in instance

```
</div><!doctype HTML>
```

and

document type does not allow element "HTML" here

```
<html lang="pl">
```

It's my code master view

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="pl">
<head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> @yield('title') </title>

    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />


    <!-- Foundation -->

    <script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700,600,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/animate.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="/js/jquery.viewportchecker"></script>

</head>
<body>
        @yield('content')

        @include('nav.footer')

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look here for how to use the language attribute [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html) - You did it right in the example above !

Comment: The code you included in your question validates. The error message you quoted says that there’s a `div` in front of the `doctype` (which is not the case in your snippet).

Answer (score -1):

You should use uppercase letters when declaring your `DOCTYPE` or you could end up getting an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```